# How to close or dipose a self host service?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that host a service, the code behind is this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(GestorAplicacionesService));
        _host.Open();
    }
    private ServiceHost _host;
}
```

I have read that it is good practice to close the service, but I don't know how to do it in this case? Because I have the main window, that if I close the application, I could close the service in the closing event. How ever, if there are some exception that could break the application that doesn't fire the closing event, then the service wouldn't be close.

So I was wondering how it would be the best way to close the service when it is hosted in a wpf application.

Thanks.

Comment: If your application gets an unexpected exception, all bets are off. Who knows whether you can even close the service at that point: maybe it was the service that crashed.

Comment: Since the OS automatically closes any listening sockets created by a process that is just being closed, I don't think it matters *that* much. Are there any other resources your service allocates that need to be freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `Closing` event and close it there. You may also want to implement the `IDisposable` interface to cope with best practises for disposable fields:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ServiceHost _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(GestorAplicacionesService));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _host.Open();
        Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _host.Close();
        _host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the best you can do. If the entire process gets shut down unexpectedly, there is not much you can do about it in your WPF application. The memory will still be returned to the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that all in app.xaml

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).host.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).host.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).host.Close();

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
```

and for threading issues please follow this link : https://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/wcf-simplified-part-7-hosting-a-wcf-service-using-wpf/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I would like to know why someone unvote you, because if it is not a good solution, we could learn why it is not.

Comment: i also have the same question.  why someone down vote this ? too simple answer ?